# Given m amount of edges within a directed graph, is there a systematic way of accounting for all unique possible combinations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, directed-graphs

Given m amount of edges within a directed graph, is there a systematic way of accounting for all unique possible combinations of said digraph with m edges?

For example, let m=2. By hand, I was able to find 9 unique possible combinations of a digraph with 2 edges. The amount of vertices in each combination varies. 
As m increases, it is getting harder to do it by hand. Does anyone know of any strategies if given m=3,4,...,n.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it, given $n$ vertices, how many unique directed graphs with m edges are there?

Comment: Also, I think whether or not the numbering of the vertices are fixed or arbitrary matters here. For example, if $n=10,m = 1$, does a directed edge from vertex 1 to 2 differs from a directed edge from vertex 4 to 5?

Comment: For the first question, I'm basically asking how to find all possible combinations of a digraph with say (for example) 3 edges. Number of vertices changes per combination.

Comment: For the second comment, they would count as the same. I tried to describe that attribute as "unique" but not too confident in my mathematical skills yet so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Even for the $m=2$ case, I can only find 7 possible combinations. Take $v_0$ as source, if both are connected to the source, {$(v_0 \rightarrow v_1,v_0 \rightarrow v_2);(v_0 \leftarrow v_1,v_0 \leftarrow v_2);(v_0 \rightarrow v_1,v_0 \leftarrow v_2)$}. And if only 1 connected to the source, {$(v_0 \rightarrow v_1, v_1 \rightarrow v_2);(v_0 \rightarrow v_1,v_1 \leftarrow v_2);(v_0 \leftarrow v_1, v_1 \leftarrow v_2);(v_0 \leftarrow v_1, v_1 \rightarrow v_2)$}

Comment: What is a "combination of a digraph"?  There are infinitely many isomorphism classes of digraphs with $2$ edges, since we can have any number of isolated vertices, so you must have some restriction in mind.  What is it?  Are you asking about unlabeled or labeled digraphs?  I doubt there is any way to do this, but it's difficult to be sure with such an imprecise question.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes loops would also count so {(v_o)--> (v_o), (v_1)-->(v_1)}, {(v_o)--> (v_o), (v_o)-->(v_1)}, {(v_o)--> (v_o), (v_o)<--(v_1)} are all valid. Also the number of vertices don't matter so {(v_o)-->(v_1), (v_2)-->(v_3)} and {(v_o)-->(v_1), (v_2) <--(v_3)} would count as some also. Note that in cases such as {(v_o)--> (v_o), (v_1)-->(v_2)} and {(v_o)--> (v_o), (v_2)-->(v_1)}, are considered the exact same (a digraph with one vertex holding a loop, and two other vertices with a directed edge from one to the other).

Comment: @saulspatz yeah sorry for my wording, still new to discrete so I'm not sure how to ask it better and don't know much of the vocabulary myself. In my most simplest description: I am trying to get all unique forms of a digraph given a specific number of edges. What I mean by unique: for example say I had two distinct digraphs A and B such that A={has one vertex with a loop}, B={has one vertex with a loop}, note that A is "shaped" similarly to B and hence not unique.

Comment: I sounds like you're talking about isomorphism classes then.  I doubt there's any practical way to do this.  I did a search for "isomorphism classes of digraphs" on OEIS and [here's](http://oeis.org/search?q=isomorphism+classes+of+digraphs&language=english&go=Search) what turned up.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh cool, don't know much about isomorphism but will definitely look into. Also, thank you for the responses everyone. <3

Comment: @saulspatz  You might be interested in the OP's [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716234/number-of-distinct-digraphs-with-3-edges/)